# Create tables based on contents of other table

Tags: t-sql, dynamic-sql, sql-server-2019

I have a table that contains names of tables to create and the columns that that table should have:

```
CREATE TABLE Tables2Create (
table_name nvarchar(256)
,colum_names nvarchar(max)
)
INSERT INTO Tables2Create VALUES ('People','Name|Occupation|Hobby')
INSERT INTO Tables2Create VALUES ('Schools','Name|Place|Type ')
```

Now I need some TSQL that will dynamically create tables for each table in the field table_names and that will split the field column_names to decide which columns each table should have. All fields can be nvarchar's.

```
CREATE TABLE People (
Name nvarchar(256)
,Occupation nvarchar(256)
,Hobby nvarchar(256)
)
```

Any idea how to do this?

Comment: This feels like a design flaw. You're storing delimited data in your database which is *always* wrong, but also you're assuming that all the columns need to be an `nvarchar`. What "age" is `N'asdajsdv  skdfjgakdf'`?

Comment: There you are again @Larnu. How are you? This time I need to import  csv files in a folder without using any other tools than SQL Server and without knowing what fields will be in the csv's and what  they contain. If somebody decides that 'OLD' is a proper age description, so be it. I just need to store the data, I will be doing no calulcations, no logic, no nothing.
Perfect datatyping would be ideal however, the world we live in is something less than ideal. I wil be changing the question to reflect that all data can and should be (n)varchar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is an example using `STRING_SPLIT` to extract the column names and `STRING_AGG` to concatenate the column names and `CREATE TABLE` statements.

```
DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(MAX);
SELECT @SQL = STRING_AGG(CreateTableStatement, '')
FROM (
    SELECT 
        'CREATE TABLE ' + QUOTENAME(table_name) + N' (' + 
        (
            SELECT STRING_AGG(QUOTENAME(value) + ' nvarchar(256)',',')
            FROM STRING_SPLIT(column_names,'|')
        )
        + N');'
    FROM dbo.Tables2Create
) AS CreateTableStatements(CreateTableStatement)

EXEC(@SQL);
```

Comment: Very similar methods in the end. :)

Comment: @Charlieface, do you mean the nested derived table queries? No good reason. I extracted the code from a working query for a more complicated use case and retained the outer one. Updated the query in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Can you do this? Yes, you can. Should you? Probably not, if I am honest. Storing delimited data, as I mention in my comment, is always a design flaw; at least normalise your design.

That being said, the method I use here is an "all in one" solution; no cursors, not iteration. As you've tagged SQL Server 2019 that means we can make use of `STRING_AGG`. This gives something like this:

```sql
USE master;
GO

CREATE DATABASE TestDB;
GO

USE TestDB;
GO

CREATE TABLE Tables2Create (table_name sysname, --correct data type for object names
                            column_names nvarchar(max)
)
INSERT INTO Tables2Create VALUES (N'People',N'Name|Occupation|Hobby')
INSERT INTO Tables2Create VALUES (N'Schools',N'Name|Place|Type ');
GO

DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(MAX),
        @CRLF nchar(2) = NCHAR(13) + NCHAR(10);

DECLARE @Delim nvarchar(10) = N',' + @CRLF + N'    '

SET @SQL = (SELECT STRING_AGG(S.SQL,'')
            FROM(SELECT @CRLF + @CRLF +
                        N'CREATE TABLE dbo.' + QUOTENAME(T2C.table_name) + N' (' + @CRLF + N'    ' +
                        STRING_AGG(QUOTENAME(SS.value) +  N' nvarchar(256)',@Delim) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY SS.[Value]) + @CRLF + N');' AS SQL
                 FROM dbo.Tables2Create T2C
                      CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(T2C.column_names,N'|') SS
                 GROUP BY T2C.table_name) S);

PRINT @SQL; --Your best friend

EXEC sys.sp_executesql @SQL;
GO

USE master;
GO

DROP DATABASE TestDB;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=1b4c9a5d64f7de98d8477c1649968f54)

Comment: I understand your hesitations about storing delimited data. Learned from your solution.  Thank you. Had a good laugh about the comment  about 'your best friend' ;)